# Creating a link, partially from stored data, with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a rails newbie.

I'm trying to create a link on a show page, with part of the data coming from a stored field which is the subdomain.  I can't save the full link before the save in the model because I'm using just the sub-domain info for a script that's running.

So, for example, I'm saving "subdomain" in the database but on a show page want to display, and link to:

```
http://<%=h @user.subdomain %>.thissite.com
```

I've tried a few ways to do this and can't get it working.  I'd really appreciate any assistance....

Comment: Is the problem storing it in the database, or reading it out and displaying it on the page?

Please provide code samples

Comment: I can store it and display it fine.  I just don't know how to create a link out of it.

I try:

<%= link_to "http://<%=h@user.subdomain %>.thissite.com", "link_to "http://<%=h@user.subdomain %>.thissite.com" %> which doesn't work, but hopefully that clarifies what I'd like to do.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html):

```
link_to "Visit Other Site", "http://www.rubyonrails.org/"
```

so, translating that to your need that becomes:

```
link_to "Click here", "http://#{@user.subdomain}.thissite.com/"
```

Comment: This will work, but it can get messy if you want to use the restful route helpers in rails along with that code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

`link_to 'test', :host => "#{@user.subdomain}.yoursite.com", :path_only => false`

You can find more information here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html Be sure to look at the options in url_for.

If you want all links you create to have the subdomain, you can also do this in your application controller:

```
def default_url_options(options)
   { :only_path => false, :host => "#{@user.subdomain}.yoursite.com" }
end
```